# Redirecting URLs with multiple parameters to clean URLs in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-parameters

I'm attempting to redirect URLs in .htaccess that have multiple parameters for example:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?p=product&id=10&parent=0
```

to a clean URL on another domain like

```
http://example2.com/product/product10/
```

I believe my normal method of redirection (using a PHP header in an index file of a directory I've created) will not work due to not being able to put `?` in a directory name.

I've done some minor .htaccess but have no experience with escaping parameters or anything and the only tutorials I can find are for escaping only a single parameter.

Can anybody give me a few pointers please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use that in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example2.com/%1/%1%2/? [R=302]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.